# My component's value in a dialog not updated to backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.5 , and now i want to ask the user to input or choose some data in my dialog (choose oneSelectMenu, or insert data in inputTextarea). I also use table to arrange the UI.

But any value from user in my dialog is not send to my backing bean.
I think it's because i used it in a dialog.

I tried to move one of my oneSelectMenu outside the dialog, and it works fine!

Any body know what's wrong? Any response will be much appreciated.

My backing bean is kind of standard getter and setter.
(I think nothing wrong with my backing bean because it works fine outside the dialog)

And this is my xhtml code :

```
<p:dialog id="dlgNew" header="New Action Item" widgetVar="dlg1" modal="true" resizable="false" 
width="40%" height="55%" appendToBody="true">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><p:outputLabel value="Detail"/></td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><p:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="40" value="#{aiBean.detail}"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p:outputLabel value="Status"/></td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><p:selectOneMenu effect="fade" value="#{aiBean.status}">    
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Not Started" itemValue="Not Started" />  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="On Progress" itemValue="On Progress" /> 
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Finished" itemValue="Finished" />               
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td>
        <td>
        <p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{aiBean.insertAi}"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="dlg1.hide()"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `p:dialog` out of `h:form` if its in any.
put `h:form` inside the `p:dialog`.

```
<p:dialog id="dlgNew" header="New Action Item" widgetVar="dlg1" modal="true" resizable="false" 
width="40%" height="55%" appendToBody="true">
   <h:form>
      ...
      ...
   </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Yeah. I also realised that I used a form in my template.

So i remove my form in my template, then put a form in my dialog.
Exactly like your answer. Thanks Kishor!

Comment: Poor answer. This answer is nowhere **explaining** the cause and the solution in clear to understand technical terms. So the asker and the future readers (and possibly also yourself!) will still have no clue why exactly having the form outside the dialog was causing trouble and why exactly moving the form has solved the problem. So, nobody really learns anything from this answer.

Comment: Yeah @BalusC , it's kinda hard to know why we need to remove all of the form, and only include the form inside the dialog.

But i read somewhere that we need to include the form inside the dialog because the appendToBody="true" part makes my dialog don't have any form, so i need to include my own form.

About removing any other form outside the dialog, maybe it could be caused by the outer form make my dialog not updated. Is it right? Or anybody know why?